# Use cases that involve calculation.Who are the actors?

Tags: uml, use-case

I am new to UML and I am modelling use case diagrams for a Pedometer application. However I am a little bit confused. Does functional requirements such **Count steps**, **Calculate distance**, **Calculate speed** be regarded as a use case and who are its actors? For a use case such as **Log in** its pretty straight forward to me that the actor is the User.

Comment: N.B. `Log in` is no UC at all since it has no added value. It is a constraint you apply to certain UCs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The physical calculation is something done under the hood in the system under consideration. The use case behind it is to "show the burned calories" or the "physical fitness gained during exercise". These are probably the use cases synthesizing these functions. Just knowing the number of steps might be some "sub-use-case" but actually not really added value. YMMV.

Now, as these "Use Cases" are actually not really ones (since they lack added value), the `User` is not the actor here. He would be the actor in UCs like named above where these functions are steps in the UC itself.

Answer (score 0):

Imho Use case analysis is best for system boundary analysis rather than system internal stuff.
So 'count steps' feels internal while 'show step counter' feels like the UI. Boundary.